# How to synchronize a Dojo JsonRestStore with database ids

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid

I have a class 'Contact' with the attributes:

```
id
name
email
```

the id is created by the database whenever a new Contact is created. These Contacts are
displayed in the UI using a Dojox DataGrid which uses a JsonRestStore.

When creating a new Contact via

```
personStore.newItem({name: "foo", email: "foo@acme.org"});
personStore.save();
```

the client executes a 'HTTP POST' request with a JSON request body which is processed by
the backend and a new Contact with a unique id is created in the database.

Now the new Contact contained by the JsonRestStore has to be updated with the id created by the backend. How can this be done? What is the expected return of the 'HTTP POST'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution for the problem in the Dojo mailing list

http://dojo-toolkit.33424.n3.nabble.com/Server-supplied-IDs-using-JsonRestStore-td177200.html